# Node + nginx reverse proxy never works until I restart nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, vagrant

I have a Node.js app that I run on port 8204 on a Vagrant VM (Ubuntu 16.04.3) (Windows 7 x64 host). Whenever I start up the Vagrant VM, ssh in and start the Node.js app like this:

```
> npm start
```

I always get the **Welcome to nginx!** screen in the browser. If I go back to my terminal and `nginx -s reload` and then `npm start` again, then the site loads properly. I have to restart nginx every time I start the VM.

Why doesn't it just work from the beginning when I start up the server? nginx is obviously running or else I wouldn't get the welcome screen. Here is my conf for this vhost:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mywebsite.development;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://mywebsite.development$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mywebsite.development;

  access_log /vagrant/nginx/logs/mywebsite.dev-access.log;
  error_log /vagrant/nginx/logs/mywebsite.dev-error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8204;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put config file on the NGINX?
If you have only one virtual host, then replace it with default virtual host which is: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Comment: I have multiple vhosts. I have all my vhost configs in a separate directory `/vagrant/nginx/vhosts/*.conf` and I include them all at the end of the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. This makes it easy to manage and edit configs for multiple vhosts in a Vagrant environment.